# Black edges appear when window is transparent

Tags: c#, user32, windows-api-code-pack

I used the following method to successfully make the window transparent, but some windows will have black edges, how should I solve it

```
WindowApi.SetWindowLong(winPtr, -20, WindowApi.GetWindowLong(winPtr, -20) | 524288);
WindowApi.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(winPtr, 0, checked((uint)config.Transparency), 2);
```

[image]

I tried the following methods to judge, although there is no black edge, but it can't make the window transparent,What should I do to make the window transparent and have no black edges

```
WindowApi.GetWindowLong(winPtr, -20)
```

Comment: If you want transparent windows, use WPF or some other XAML equivalent.  Gone are the days of hoki "set transparent color" which was always hit or miss.

Comment: My program is to make other windows transparent instead of making itself transparent